# Cannot Use Text String with Comparison Operator as Input to Filter()

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to use selected items from a slicer as the input to a filter statement. To get the slicer selections, I am building up a text string, which has a comparison operator.  The chart that I am using this in, then gives an error, 'Calculation error in measure ... of type text to type true/false'.

I have a measure that I created to count the number of items opened & closed within a given timeframe.  I have a date slicer, from which I am successfully pulling the start/stop dates and using those as inputs to my Filter statement, and counting the rows returned.

I am now trying to add a name selection from a slicer to the Filter statement and not having much luck.

I am pulling the names selected from a slicer with the following code.

```
Names = CONCATENATEX(
ALLSELECTED(Table[Column]),
"Table[Column]="&Table[Column],
"  || ")
```

This gives me a text string like, 'Table[Column]="John Smith" || Table[column] "Jane Smith"

When I put this into my filter statement

```
Filter(Working Filters && (Names))
```

That's when I get my error.  If I type the statement in directly, it works.  But that doesn't help me, since I will not know what is selected

```
Filter(Working Filters && (Table[Column]="John Smith" || Table[column] "Jane Smith")
```

How can I use my text String as the input to the filter?  Or is there a different way that i could get my slicer selections into filter?

Comment: What is your data model? Feels to me Power bi should give you this functionality already but you might miss a relation?

Comment: In essence, this is an issue tracking, metrics, report.  I am trying to show how many items were opened and closed in a given week/month/quarter, by using the detected  /closing date to determine how many items were opened/Closed.  I am trying to add in the person(s) who logged the item in the calculation of the measure.

Comment: Please make a snapshot of the data model with the tables you have.

Answer (score 0):

The `FILTER` function doesn't take text arguments like that. To read values from a slicer, you can use `SELECTEDVALUE` (for a single value) or `VALUES` (for possibly multiple values). However, most of the time, if your tables and relationships are set up correctly, you shouldn't have to do that manually unless you are using a slicer to set a parameter rather than as a filter.

Let's say you have `Table1` and `Table2` that are not related and you are using `Table2[Column2]` as a slicer. Then you could write a filter like this:

```
FILTER( Table1, Table1[Column1] IN VALUES( Table2[Column2] ) )
```

Thus even though `Table1` and `Table2` are not related, you are only allowing values in `Table1[Column1]` that match the values you've selected with your `Table2[Column2]` slicer.